# how to convert .sou file to .sln

Tags: asp.net

I downloded asp.net file but it shows in .sou extension it is not opend in my vs2008 how can i convert .sou file to .sln

Answer (score 4):

The **.sou** file isn't the equivalent of a **.sln** file. [They do different things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx).

In your *Visual Studio* go to `File -> Open Website` and navigate to your folder instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. .sln files store completely different data than .suo files.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx):

> - **.sln**: Organizes projects, project items and solution items into the solution by providing the environment with references to their locations on disk.
> - **.suo**: Records all of the options that you might associate with your solution so that each time you open it, it includes customizations that you have made.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the .sou file and .sln files ccontain different info. See descriptions here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx  It won't contain information that can converted.

The best way is to [create a blank solution file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx) and add the existing projects to it one by one.